# How to get emitted events corresponding to sent transaction

Tags: solidity, web3js

I want to write smart contract which saves hash value and return identifier of that hash to check saved hash later.

My contract is like:

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.25 <0.7.0;
pragma experimental ABIEncoderV2;

contract SaveHash {
    event HashSaved(uint id);
    Hash[] hashes;
    function save(Hash memory hash) public {
        // some process
        emit HashSaved(hashes.length - 1);
    }
}
```

However, I don't understand how to know event emitted by contract is corresponding to which transaction.

How can I know by which transaction an event is created?

Answer (score -1):

Events are stored in the `logs` section of a transaction (also known as topics). Events are ABI encoded. You can match raw hex data from the logs section of a transaction with events if you know the contract data.

To go reverse order, to get the transaction of an event, you can query Ethereum node to list [all the past events](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.2.9/web3-eth-contract.html#getpastevents) (web3.js example). The transaction hash is within the return values. Then you can call `web3.eth.getTransactionReceipt()` for this transaction hash to get the full transaction details.